# How to set a variable based on the first string in the URL after a symbol?

Tags: javascript, jquery

At the moment I am doing this:

```
var token = document.location.href.split('?_sft_category=')[1];
```

Which is ok if my URL is:

```
http://www.example.com/xchanges/results/?_sft_category=sky
```

I get `sky` in that case as a var, but if my URL becomes

```
http://www.example.com/xchanges/results/?_sft_category=sky#comboFilters%5BAgency%5D=.TBWA
```

In that case I obviously get everything after `=` while instead I would like to get ONLY the first string after `'?_sft_category='`

Comment: Do you ever attempt to research anything yourself? Your question asking rate - for very simple issues - is frankly ridiculous.

Comment: when you are doing tons of lines of coding with no colleagues and you are a designer and not a programmer, I can assure you that by the time I ask a question I researched for tons of other answers for any other questions I have. But thanks.. anyway, this is not a duplicate of that SO question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
url = "http://www.example.com/xchanges/results/?_sft_category=sky";
alert(url.split('?_sft_category=')[1].match(/[A-z]+/));
url ="http://www.example.com/xchanges/results/?_sft_category=sky#comboFilters%5BAgency%5D=.TBWA";
alert(url.split('?_sft_category=')[1].match(/[A-z]+/));
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hsebt2ey/1/)**

Comment: that if you have a defined URL tho

Comment: Check my answer might it help you

Comment: Welcome  @rob.m enjoy!!!